# SSIS cannot see any files in a network share

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have an SSI Spackage that looks at a path \\FileshareServer\Folder. When I run this in VS everything is fine.
If I load it to the server the messages returned are that the For Each Loop found no files.

There are nearly 1.5K files in this directory.

The pattern its matching is *.* and all files in this directory are .csv

If I change the directory to be a local drive (D:\Folder) it finds the files and works.

I tried mapping the network share as a drive and referenced it like S:\Folder but that gave me the same empty enumerator.

The SQL Agent service account has access to this folder because 1) im not getting access denied, and 2) Other jobs access this share (just different folders, and this inherits its permissions from the parent folder)

Im completely baffled by this and its been doing my head in for 2 days

Comment: If it's finding no files, that certainly sounds like a permission error. UNC paths start with `\\ ` not `\ `; could this be as simple as a typographical error?

Comment: Perhaps try a command step in your SQL Agent job with `DIR \\FileshareServer\Folder` and see what happens.

Comment: The typo was in my post. The directory does start with \\ in the package

Comment: Just edited my question to see that I have to escape the double backslash as \\\\  for it to show as \\